# All my MediaWiki pages are blank

Tags: php, mediawiki

All of a sudden, all my Mediawiki pages are blank. If I click the edit field, the content is still, there. Ive checked the sqlite file and it looks just fine. Ive turned on debugging output and get the following:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 881

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 882

Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 886

Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 881

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 882

Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 886

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 881

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 882

Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 886

Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 881

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 882

Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 886

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 8 in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 907
```

Are these errors most likely the cause of the issue? If so, how do I resolve it? And if not, anyone have any idea on what might be the problem?

Comment: Someone update your version of PHP?

Comment: As they are warnings they shouldn't be code-breaking

Comment: The wiki does load up, just without any content ;)

Comment: General debugging instructions: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Blank_page

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the issue. Its described in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58640). Its apparently fixed in the Mediawiki master. The released versions are not compatible with PCRE 8.34.

Comment: The issue disappeared in my case after upgrading to 1.22.6

Comment: Thank you, my issue was fixed for now by applying the [(obsolete) quick-and-dirty patch](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/attachment.cgi?id=14135) and adding "?action=purge" to the url of my Wiki page to purge the cache, as your link suggests.

Answer (score 8):

You have to change includes/MagicWord.php as shown here:
[here](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/122449/1/includes/MagicWord.php)

Replace

```
$group = "(?P<{$i}_{$name}>" . preg_quote( $syn, '/' ) . ')';
```

With

```
$it = strtr( $i, '0123456789', 'abcdefghij' );
$group = "(?P<{$it}_{$name}>" . preg_quote( $syn, '/' ) . ')';
```

After Replacing this you have to purge all sites. This can be done on single pages with adding "?action=purge" to the url of the page or for all sites by running this in command line from the maintenance directory:

```
php purgeList.php --purge --all
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms after upgrading from Trusty to Xenial (Ubuntu), but it was not a PCRE issue. in my case it was resolved by disabling the Widgets extension, which I did by commenting out this line in the LocalSettings.php ...

```
require_once("$IP/extensions/Widgets/Widgets.php");
```

I have the v1.0 of Widgets on v1.28.0 of Mediawiki.